# Adjusting Relevancy in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, spring-mvc, lucene, elasticsearch

I have inherited an application to work on that has a search component that queries a some elasticSearch Indexes. ElasticSearch is a black box for our team. We don't know much about it at all except for configuring the cluster startup and elasticsearch.yml file.

There has been a bug filed related to 'ElasticSearch relevancy' and I'm not sure what changes would be needed in elasticsearch. Could someone elabororate on this subject? We have just begun to start learning on elasticsearch.

> ```
> 1). Typing "Citig" returns only one result - "CITIGATE BROAD STREET 
>     INC." and does not return Citigroup 
> 2). Typing "Citigr" to "Citigrou" returns nothing. It's not until 
>     you type "Citigroup" that  you get multiple hits
> 3)."FORD MOTOR COMPANY" brings many relevant results, but strangely does not bring up 
>     "FORD  MOTOR COMPANY".
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 and 2 is simply how search in ElasticSearch works by default. It's not a regex search unless you specify it as a regex search by adding * as a wildcard. If you enter "Citig" it will match documents that have phrases like "Citig Inc" or "Citig LLC", but not "Citigroup". The document needs to have "Citig" as a token, basically.

Now if you did a regex search instead of a regular search, then yes it would match Citigroup, but that's not the default search behavior. You'd need to change that.

3, check if the field it's searching in has a keyword analyzer. If so, then it's always looking for an exact match, so that's why it's not matching. If it's a standard analyzer, that shouldn't happen if it also has a whitespace filter. To fix this, you'd need to change the analyzer to a standard analyzer and reindex the data. Alternatively, you can just do a simply terms filter query for each of the tokens, but I'd only go that route if you can't reindex the data.
ElasticSearch is hard as hell, your team better be prepared to learn :) I've been hacking ElasticSearch for the past year, and it still boggles my mind.

Comment: Thanks Henley. Getting pulled into ES now!

Answer (score 1):

On items 1 and 2, there isn't enough information here to be certain, but I strongly suspect you are seeing the results of stemming.  If your analyzer is of type `english`, that is probably the case.

A stemmer is designed to reduce a word to it's stem, by removing prefixes, suffixes, etc.  Since "-ate" is a common suffix in english, "citigate" may be reduced to "citig".  Language is complicated, and stemmers aren't perfect, as evinced by this example, but they generally do a lot more good than harm.  "Citigroup", on the other hand, probably is not changed by the stemmer.

You can take a look at some documentation of the [English Steming algorithm](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html), to get a better understanding of this.

If you want to search with a wildcard at the end of the query, you can use a [`prefix` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html)

For number three, I don't know why it wouldn't be picking that up, unless the record you are looking for is just being found after a lot of other good hits, with a lower score, or perhaps the query isn't being sorted by score, or something of that nature.  Not enough here for me to guess at.  If you want to make sure you get an exact match on multiple terms, you can use a [`text_phrase` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-text-query.html)